# remove an element from list object

Tags: java

I have a List object which holds 10 elements, i have to do conditional check and remove some of the elements from the list. I have done as below, but it is not working as expected, any inputs?

```
List<MyDTO> myList = new ArrayList<MyDTO>(); //myist.size () is 10
```

I want to check as below:

```
for(MyDTO res : myList){
    if(res.getResult().equals("cancel")){
     myList.remove()
  }
}
```

As shown in above code, if res.getResult() is "cancel" i want to remove that particular object from the list(myList). Is it the correct way to remove an element completely from list based on conditional check?

Comment: What happens when you compile and run this code?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `removeIf` on your list, for example if you had list of `Integer`s ranging from 1 to 10 and you wanted to remove `Integer`s larger than 4, you would do:

```
yourListHere.removeIf(x -> x > 4);
```

Resulting list would contain: 1, 2, 3 and 4

Read here about `removeIf`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-

**BONUS**

Additional resources if you are unfamiliar with Java 8 features:

Lambdas - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Functional Interfaces - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Comment: Cool! didn't know about ```removeIf````.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `removeIf` you can use the Java stream solution:

```
List<MyDTO> newList = myList.stream()
                            .filter(s -> !s.getResult().equals("cancel"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This might be more convenient when the length of the input list and the number of elements to remove is relatively large.

Answer (score 0):

Use *removeIf*:

```
default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)
```

> Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given
>   predicate. Errors or runtime exceptions thrown during iteration or by
>   the predicate are relayed to the caller.

In your example:

```
myList.removeIf(res -> res.getResult().equals("cancel"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If use Java 8:

```
myList.removeIf(x -> x.getResult().equals("cancel"));
```

If older (6,7):

```
public class MyDTO {

    private String result;
    (...)

    public MyDTO(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    (...)

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final MyDTO other = (MyDTO) obj;

        return !((this.result == null) ? (other.result != null) : !this.result.equals(other.result));
    }

    (...)

}
```

then:

```
MyDTO toRemove = new MyDTO("cancel");

while(myList.contains(toRemove))
    myList.remove(toRemove);
```

or:

```
List<MyDTO> toRemove = new ArrayList<MyDTO>(); 

for(MyDTO res : myList){
    if(res.getResult().equals("cancel")){
     toRemove.add(res);
  }
}
myList.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Without overriding the equals method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size() ; i++)
    if(myList.get(i).getResult().equals("cancel"))
       myList.remove(i);
```

or:

```
Iterator<MyDTO> i = myList.iterator();

while (i.hasNext())
    if(i.next().getResult().equals("cancel"))
         i.remove();
```